# Function Composition: Augmenting an existing function with additional function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function-composition

I import a library with a function and would like to replace that function with a function that takes the original function as an argument together with an additional function.

The original function might be logThis:

```
function logThis() {console.log('this'));
```

I can create a new function which executes logThis and then logs 'that';

```
function logThisThenThat() {
  logThis();
  console.log('that');
}
```

I would like to replace logThis with a new function which executes the original function and thereafter another function? Is this possible with function composition or will I have to create a new function with a different name which is made up of the original function and additional functions.

Something along the lines of:

```
logThis = compose(logThis, logThat);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function like this.

```js
function logThis() {
 console.log("this");
}

function logThat() {
 console.log("that");
}

let compose = (...func) => ()=> {
 let functions = func;
 functions.forEach((fn) => fn());
}

logThis = compose(logThis, logThat);
logThis();
```

Adding `(...func)` as parameters, you can execute 3, 4 any amount of functions you like/need.

Note: *Edit the snippet to match the question. The [selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54113542/1757214) by @mark-meyer is correct.*

Answer (score 1):

You can override the existing function with a new one.

Keep a copy of the original like this...

```
_logThis = logThis;
```

...and then make your new version call the original one...

```
function logThis() {
    _logThis();
    // your other function call or new code goes here
}
```

This isn't a particularly good idea though, since that will modify what happens for *every single existing call* to that method.  This needs to be handled with care.

Also, scope is a big factor here.  This is a basic example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: That's exactly what I did and it works. I thought it looks quite pythonic and that there might be a different more javascripty method out there.

Comment: I doubt you'll ever see extending functions being a native thing since it's so straight forward to do.  I'm sure there are 3rd party libraries out there that make it look fluffy, but it'll do ^^ that at it's lowest level.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass `logThis()` into your `compose()` function, you will hold a reference to it in the closure, so it will live on when you make a new `logThis()`. The name isn't really that important so long as you rename in an order that lets you get the reference to the old `logThis()` before you point the name at a new function. For example, the right side of `logThis = compose(logThis, logThat)` runs before the name assignment below, so you capture the function reference before reassigning the name:

```js
function logThis() {console.log('this')};
function logThat() {console.log('that')};

let compose = (f1, f2) => () => {
    f1()
    f2()
}

logThis = compose(logThis, logThat)
logThis()
```

Comment: excellent... that's exactly what i was looking for. is it possible to make this work with n number of functions instead of just two? although in my current use case i will only need two and i could just add more functions one by one.

Comment: Yeah @DennisBauszus , you just need to pass an array of functions or capture all the arguments. Something like `let compose = (...fns) => () => fns.forEach(f=>f())`

Comment: Cool... Just seen the latest answer from manuerumx who suggested the same. Works a treat. Thanks.